# Time conversion seconds to minutes

Tags: matlab

I have a streaming time vector that records time in second. the resolution is 250 Hz, meaning that I have 250 samples for every second. I'd like to represent that in Matlab. I used the following line

```
        time(in)= datestr(time(in)/(24*60*60), 'HH:MM:SS.FFF');
```

but I got the followoing error:

```
        In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.
```

Time(in) is a single element of the vector Time, which is the recorded time in seconds. I think I got what you mean, so the results of datestr will give multiple outputs (hours, minutes, secs, fraction of seconds,...) right? I only want a single output showing the corresponding time in minutes (i.e. 5.45 which means 5 minutes, and 45 seconds). I wan't to plot my data with respect to minutes not seconds, this is my motive of the question

How can i do t correctly?

Comment: Can you add a [mcve]? This has nothing to do with covering time, its just you are trying to store in `time(in)` <- single item, something that is likely more than one item

Comment: Time(in) is a single element of the vector Time, which is the recorded time in seconds. I think I got what you mean, so the results of datestr will give multiple outputs (hours, minutes, secs, fraction of seconds,...) right? I only want a single output showing the corresponding time in minutes (i.e. 5.45 which means 5 minutes, and 45 seconds). I wan't to plot my data with respect to minutes not seconds, this is my motive of the question.

Comment: Yes, but no. `time(in)` is also where you are triying to store the output, that has multiple values, not one. The error is telling you you have `A=B` and they are not the same size, or in your case, `size(time(in))` is not `size(datestr(....    ))`. You are triying to put 5 apples in a box where only 1 fits. Try, as a test, chaning your code do `time_out{in}=datestr(time(in)/(24*60*60), 'HH:MM:SS.FFF');`. You will see no error.